# Cleaning Dataframe Using Columns Conditions - Python/Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda3

I have a dataframe as following:

```
Year-Week  Ticket   Policy
2022-25    12502    COMPLIED
2022-26    12502    NOT COMPLIED
2022-20    12502    COMPLIED
2022-15    12502    COMPLIED
2022-26    12471    COMPLIED
2022-24    12409    COMPLIED
2022-26    12409    NOT COMPLIED
2022-25    12406    COMPLIED
```

There are cases that are duplicated and that is okay since they are from different year-week, however, how could I standarized that the same ticket have the same policy. E.g: If a ticket in a week has "NOT COMPLIED", the policy should be the same for that ticket no matter the week, so, should be something like this:

**Output Sample**

```
Year-Week  Ticket   Policy
2022-25    12502    NOT COMPLIED
2022-26    12502    NOT COMPLIED
2022-20    12502    NOT COMPLIED
2022-15    12502    NOT COMPLIED
2022-26    12471    COMPLIED
2022-24    12409    NOT COMPLIED
2022-26    12409    NOT COMPLIED
2022-25    12406    COMPLIED
```

I was thinking this should be done by using an if function in python.

Comment: The question is asking to fix them but I don't see how you can pick one if there are multiple policies for a ticket number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year-Week": ['2022-25', '2022-26'], "Ticket": [12502, 12502], "Policy": ["COMPLIED", "NOT COMPLIED"]})
policies = df[['Ticket', 'Policy']].groupby('Ticket').max()
new_values = df[['Ticket']].merge(policies, on='Ticket')
df.update(new_values)
```

Please, note that you can use code above only for this case, where "NO COMPLIED" is longer than "COMPLIED". In other cases you should use another aggregation functions.